# Dynamic Pivot with Concatenation

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How should SQL be modified to concatenate text "Name" into column header and 2 name fields for pivoted data?

I have table like:

| UmpID | FirstN | LastN | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | H | J |
| 2 | B | I | S |
| 3 | C | J | A |
| 4 | D | K | J |
| 5 | E | L | S |
| 6 | F | M | J |
| 7 | G | N | J |

Query:

```
SET NoCount ON;

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

WITH GS AS(
SELECT LastN, Age, QUOTENAME(Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN)) As GrpSeq FROM Umpires),
DS AS
(SELECT DISTINCT GrpSeq FROM GS),
CS AS
(SELECT STRING_AGG(GrpSeq,',') AS G FROM DS)

SELECT @cols = G FROM CS

SELECT @sql = 'SELECT *
            FROM (SELECT LastN, Age, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) As GrpSeq FROM Umpires) AS Q
            PIVOT(Min(LastN) FOR GrpSeq IN(' + @cols + ')) AS P;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Produces output:

| Age | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | J |  |  |  |
| J | H | K | M | N |
| S | I | L |  |  |

I would like to produce:

| Age | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 | Name4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | J, C |  |  |  |
| J | H, A | K, D | M, F | N, G |
| S | I, B | L, E |  |  |

Attempt at simple concatenation of fields in inner SELECT and referencing that alias field in PIVOT for building @sql string generated error:

> select statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

Attempts at concatenating 'Name' string just triggers:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Name'

As side note, this is easily accomplished in Access query, although might be horribly slow with very large dataset because of DCount() domain aggregate function:

```
TRANSFORM Max([LastN] & ", " & [FirstN]) AS FullName
SELECT Umpires.Age
FROM Umpires
GROUP BY Umpires.Age
PIVOT "Name" & DCount("*","Umpires","Age='" & [Age] & "' AND UmpID<=" & [UmpID]);
```

I can also produce in a static SQLServer pivot with known number of column header values:

```
WITH DS AS(
SELECT Age, LastN + ', ' + FirstN AS FN, 'Name' + CAST(Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) AS VARCHAR) As GrpSeq FROM Umpires)

SELECT * FROM (SELECT Age, FN, GrpSeq FROM DS) AS Q PIVOT(Max(FN) FOR GrpSeq IN([Name1],[Name2],[Name3],[Name4])) P;
```

Comment: @Thom A, how could you have edited so quickly? I was trying to fix but you already had it done when I tried to save. Thank you. I need to get better at building tables.

Comment: Find & Replace `+`->`|`, fix `| @cols |`, remove multiple excess lines. Took about 20 seconds in VSCode.

Comment: I'm not sure what's tripping you up. Why not create a second variable that does `[1] AS Name1, ... [N] AS NameN` select string, `CONCAT(FirstName, ',', LastName)` before pivoting it, and then do what you already did. Oh, and feel free to stop using PIVOT syntax altogether, it's just bad because it's hard to control the output, conditional aggregation is much easier to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this mayhaps:

```sql
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @cols2 NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  *
INTO    #data
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1, N'A', N'H', N'J')
    ,   (2, N'B', N'I', N'S')
    ,   (3, N'C', N'J', N'A')
    ,   (4, N'D', N'K', N'J')
    ,   (5, N'E', N'L', N'S')
    ,   (6, N'F', N'M', N'J')
    ,   (7, N'G', N'N', N'J')
) t (UmpID,FirstN,LastN,Age)

;WITH GS AS(
    SELECT  LastN, Age
    ,   Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) AS GrpSeq
    FROM    #data
    )
,DS AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT GrpSeq
    FROM    GS
    )
,CS AS (
    SELECT  STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(GrpSeq),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY GrpSeq) AS G
    ,   STRING_AGG(CONCAT(QUOTENAME(GrpSeq), ' AS Name', GrpSeq),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY GrpSeq) AS G2
    FROM    DS
    )
SELECT  @cols = G
,   @cols2 = G2
FROM    CS

SELECT  @sql = 'SELECT Age, ' + @cols2 + N'
            FROM (SELECT CONCAT(LastN, '','', FirstN) AS LastN, Age, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) As GrpSeq FROM #data) AS Q
            PIVOT(Min(LastN) FOR GrpSeq IN(' + @cols + ')) AS P;';

EXEC    sp_executesql @sql;
```

I created a second variable called `@cols2` that does the `[1] AS Name1, ... [N] AS NameN` select string, concated `CONCAT(LastN, '','', FirstN)` to create first + last name combo, and then did what you already did.

I also added WITHIN GROUP thing to STRING_AGG to ensure correctly ordered columns.

The conditional aggregation version (some code incorporated from above):

```sql
;WITH GS AS(
    SELECT  LastN, Age
    ,   Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) AS GrpSeq
    FROM    #data
    )
,DS AS (
    SELECT  DISTINCT GrpSeq
    FROM    GS
    )
,CS AS (
    SELECT  STRING_AGG(CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN GrpSeq = ', GrpSeq, ' THEN LastN END)', ' AS Name', GrpSeq),',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY GrpSeq) AS G3
    FROM    DS
    )
SELECT  @cols = G3
FROM    CS

SELECT  @sql = '
   SELECT Age, ' + @cols + N'
   FROM (SELECT CONCAT(LastN, '','', FirstN) AS LastN, Age, Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY Age ORDER BY Age, LastN) As GrpSeq FROM #data) AS Q
   GROUP BY Age
'
```

Comment: I removed the SELECT INTO and this works. But how does it know to use Umpires table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... You can just replace #data with whatever table you have in your real database

Comment: I copied a pass-through query and replaced all the code in the copy. Somehow it still knows to use the Umpires table. Interesting. I will have to test making a pass-through from scratch.

Comment: The conditional agg version is not working. Says **Unclosed quotation mark** and **Incorrect syntax near '**

Comment: Okay, I missed the closing apostrophe at end of your code. All good now. And conditional aggregation is not what I was expecting. I like. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad you got it working!